# Why does array(\value{counter}) and array(1) give different vertical alignment? (arrayjobx)

Tags: vertical-alignment

I have one-cell array, called `\SingleCell`, using `arrayjobx`, into which I've assigned the value "R11". I have a 1 × 2 `tabular`, with `\SingleCell(1)` in the first column and a comma "," in the second column. I also have a counter, `someCounter`, which has the value 1.

I would think that `\SingleCell(1)` should be in all ways identically treated as `SingleCell(\value{someCounter})`. But it's not: In the first table with `\SingleCell(1)`, both cells share the same baseline. In the second, otherwise identical,  table with `SingleCell(\value{someCounter})`, the "R11" appears well below the comma's baseline.

What can be different about `\SingleCell(1)` and `SingleCell(\value{someCounter})` that causes this behavior? MWE and its output follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\leavevmode\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{0.75cm}}
\newcounter{someCounter}
\newarray\SingleCell
\begin{document}
\setcounter{someCounter}{1}
\SingleCell(1)={R11}
%   Table where array element is referenced by "(1)"
\begin{tabular}{|Q c|}
\hline
\SingleCell(1) &,\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

%   Table where array element is referenced by "\value{counter}"
\begin{tabular}{|Q c|}
\hline
\SingleCell(\value{someCounter}) &,\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `\value{someCounter}` instead of `\thesomeCounter` (or `\arabic{someCounter}`)? Using `\value` should be reserved for computations and `\if...` conditionals.

Comment: The macro-name `\value` is somewhat misleading. `\value{someCounter}` expands to `\c@someCounter` which in turn is a `\countdef`-token denoting a specific `\count`-register. Denoting a specific `\count`-register does not necessarily mean getting delivered the value stored therein. It might also mean assigning it a new value, e.g., `\c@someCounter=...`, or focusing on the register number. To make sure to obtain the plain value in Arabic numerals instead of having the thing interpreted in whatsoever way, put `\number` or `\the` in front: `\number\value{someCounter}` or `\the\value{someCounter}`.

Comment: I appreciate learning why `value{someCounter}` is not equivalent to perhaps simply `1` or other expressions. But doesn't there remain a basic question: Doesn't the fact that "R11" is rendered in both cases mean that the correct value was retrieved from `\SingleCell` in both cases? And thus why should it matter to `tabular` which way "R11" was referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mico says in the comments, using `\value{someCounter}` outside of operations involving either conditionals (e.g., `\ifnum\value{someCounter}>0...\fi` or outright computations (e.g., adding the values of two counters) is wrong.

This is a misuse of `\value` because  the problem disappears if you use `\the\value{someCounter}`, `\thesomeCounter` or `\arabic{someCounter}`.

Explicitly, the problem does not occur in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\leavevmode\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{0.75cm}}
\newcounter{someCounter}
\newarray\SingleCell
\begin{document}
  \setcounter{someCounter}{1}
  \SingleCell(1)={R11}
  \begin{tabular}{|Q c|}
    \hline
    \SingleCell(1) &,\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{|Q c|}
    \hline
    \SingleCell(\arabic{someCounter}) &,\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{|Q c|}
    \hline
    \SingleCell(\thesomeCounter) &,\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{|Q c|}
    \hline
    \SingleCell(\the\value{someCounter}) &,\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: I think you should point out more strongly that using `\value{someCounter}` outside of operations involving either conditionals (e.g., `\ifnum\value{someCounter}>0...\fi` or outright computations (e.g., adding the values of two counters) is wrong. The OP shouldn't be using `\value{someCounter}` the way he/she does in the example code.